# How to increase the volume of AudioRecord?

Tags: java, android

The audio is recorder as expected but I realized the volume is too low.
Is there a way to increase the volume of the recording?

How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems hardware problem rather than software, if you want to get some help then you should post your issue with the relevant code.

Comment: I have updated the source code for record service class, plz check and give solution as soon as possible